# Executing stored procedure in mysql takes too long time than executing on other machine

Tags: mysql

While Executing stored procedure in my machine it takes too long time than executing on other machine.

Comment: Is the other machine the same? Is the data the same?

Comment: @Teneff - No that machine is different users machine and yes data and database is same in both machine.